# Linq to SQL: specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I want to query to a book in my library database, so I wrote this code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Book
/// </summary>
public partial class Book
{
    public static List<Book> GetQueryBooks(string query)
    {
        // Init db
        LibraryDataClassesDataContext db = new LibraryDataClassesDataContext();
        return db.Books.Where(b => b.Title.Contains(query) || b.Author.Contains(query)).ToList();

    } 
}
```

But I do not get why I get a "InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid" on the return?

Comment: Are you sure that this `Book` class extends the `LibraryDataClassesDataContext` `Book` class? That looks like a namespace issue.

Comment: Where do you get the exception? What's the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are missing a namespace - so `Book` here (in the `class` definition) refers to `global::Book` - rather than whatever-your-LINQ-namespace-is `Book`. Essentially, then, your `partial class Book` is a *completely different type* to the `Book` that the `LibraryDataClassesDataContext` knows about.

Try:

```
namespace The.Correct.Namespace
{
    public partial class Book
    {
        public static List<Book> GetQueryBooks(string query)
        {
            // Init db
            LibraryDataClassesDataContext db = new LibraryDataClassesDataContext();
            return db.Books.Where(b => b.Title.Contains(query) || b.Author.Contains(query)).ToList();

        } 
    }     
}
```

where `The.Correct.Namespace` is the namespace that `LibraryDataClasses.designer.cs` (I'm guessing on the file name here) is using.

Comment: Indeed Book refered to global::Book. I just deleted my LibraryDataClasses.dbml and recreated it. That solved my problem. Thanks for your tip!